# Refresh ComboBox with DropDownOpened result in loosing selected

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a ComboBox with entries of my active network interfaces. I like to refresh the entries every time a user opens the DropDown.

Sadly if the ComboBox is opened and then closed (with the arrow on the right side) the selected entry isn't shown anymore. The ComboBox shows empty.
[My ComboBox before and after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOmdr.png)

If I remove DropDownOpened event the selected item is shown in the ComboBox after open-closing the DropDown.

Thanks for your help.

This is my view:

```
                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding HostInterfaces}"
                              SelectedItem="{Binding HostInterfaceSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"
                              DisplayMemberPath="Indicator">
                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="DropDownOpened">
                                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=DropDownOpenedCommand, Mode=OneWay}" />
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    </ComboBox>
```

This is my view model:

```
    private RelayCommand _dropDownOpenedCommand;
    public ICommand DropDownOpenedCommand => _dropDownOpenedCommand ??
                                             (_dropDownOpenedCommand =
                                                 new RelayCommand(ExecuteDropDownOpenedCommand));

    private void ExecuteDropDownOpenedCommand(object obj)
    {
        HostInterfaces.Clear();

        // add several entries
        _hostInterfaces.Add( ... );
    }

    private readonly ObservableCollection<HostNetworkInterfaceEntry> _hostInterfaces = new ObservableCollection<HostNetworkInterfaceEntry>();
    public ObservableCollection<HostNetworkInterfaceEntry> HostInterfaces => _hostInterfaces;
    private HostNetworkInterfaceEntry _hostInterfaceSelected;
    public HostNetworkInterfaceEntry HostInterfaceSelected
    {
        get => _hostInterfaceSelected;
        set
        {
            if (value == null) return;
            if (value == _hostInterfaceSelected) return;
            _hostInterfaceSelected = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(HostInterfaceSelected));
        }
    }
```

My HostNetWorkInterfaceEntry class:

```
public class HostNetworkInterfaceEntry
{
    public HostNetworkInterfaceEntry(string name, IPAddress address)
    {
        Name = name;
        Address = address;
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public IPAddress Address { get; private set; }
    public string Indicator => (Address != null ? $"{Address}   {Name}" : $"{Name}");
}
```

Comment: `value == _hostInterfaceSelected` do reference equals ... obvious solution is to provide own implementation (override `object.Equals` and related) ... also it is possible that `SelectedItem` is nullify when there is no items ... so you need to store before clear localy and restore it after elements are added

Comment: You are clearing the `HostInterfaces.Clear();`, Keep track of the selected value and when filling, select the right item again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Senir and @Jeroen van Langen. Your hints lead me to the solution.

I had to modify the property HostInterfaceSelected and also the ExecuteDropDownOpenedCommand method.

```
public HostNetworkInterfaceEntry HostInterfaceSelected
{
    get => _hostInterfaceSelected;
    set
    {
        // removed that -> if (value == null) return;
        if (value == _hostInterfaceSelected) return;
        _hostInterfaceSelected = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(HostInterfaceSelected));
    }
}

private void ExecuteDropDownOpenedCommand(object obj)
{
    var saveSelected = HostInterfaceSelected; // added this
    HostInterfaces.Clear();

    // add several entries
    _hostInterfaces.Add( ... );

    // restore saved to HostInterfaceSelected 
    if (saveSelected != null)
        HostInterfaceSelected = _hostInterfaces.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == saveSelected.Name && s.Address != null && s.Address.Equals(saveSelected.Address));
}
```